# Redirect /questions to /question?sort=LAST

Tags: feature-request, tabs

Currently, `/questions` directly shows you the questions tab you visited last (without redirecting).

This would work just fine, if it wasn't for multi-tab browsing.

Consider the following scenario:

1. Click `Questions` to visit `/questions`.
2. It opens the questions tab you visited last (e. g. `Newest Questions`).
3. Click `featured` to open `Bounty Questions` in a new tab (`/questions?sort=featured`).
4. Refresh the first tab (current displaying `Newest Questions`).
5. Now the first tab opens `Bounty Questions` instead.

It's just a minor annoyance, but it could be fixed easily by making `/questions` redirect to `/questions?sort=LAST`, where `LAST` is the user's last choice among `newest`, `featured`, etc.